# ray from the origin of a sphere to the radius

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

In my previous post [shifting a sphere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110799/shifting-a-sphere-in-code-from-texample-net), I have two spheres which were lifted from [texexamples.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/)

On the left bottom side, there is a sphere with a ray from the center to the radius of the sphere.

I can't figure out what the code was for that.  I would like to generate a ray on my bigger sphere (left side).

I am not sure how though since that code is a little much for me.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I had the wrong link up for texexamples.

Comment: Are you referring to the line NP?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina the line from the origin that forms the angle beta.  bottom left picture

Comment: It's the line OP, I think. `\draw[->] (O) -- (P);` in the linked texamples.net post.

Comment: @hpesoj626 that is the bottom right picture that has O to P.

Comment: @dustin Oh. The segment in the bottom left picture is not labeled OP. But the `tikz` coordinates are named `(O)` and `(P)`.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I also want my ray on the left side not the right though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the desired ray:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
%% helper macros

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % "THE GLOBE" showcase

\def\R{2.5} % sphere radius
\def\angEl{35} % elevation angle
\def\angPhi{-48} % longitude of point P
\def\angBeta{-164} % latitude of point P

\filldraw[ball color=white] (0,0) circle (\R);
\foreach \t in {-80,-60,...,80} { \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }
\foreach \t in {-5,-35,...,-175} { \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }

\pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
\LongitudePlane[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhi}

\node[label=above:$\mathbf{O}$] (O) at (0,0) {};
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate[mark coordinate] (P);
\draw[->] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$\mathbf{P}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what piece of code are speaking of?  Isn't that the whole code from the page?

Comment: @dustin Sorry about that. I pasted the wrong code. Fixed now.

Comment: how can rotate arrow head along the latitude axis `-180`?

Comment: @dustin change the value of `\angBeta`, for example: `\def\angBeta{-171}`. (I hope this is what you wanted).

Comment: yes you are amazing at this.

Comment: I added those pieces of code but nothing changed.  No arrow was added.

Comment: @dustin as you can see in the image of my answer, the ray is drawn, so perhaps your code changed something?

Comment: @dustin I've updated my answer. I simply changed the values for some angles, so the ray points in the desired direction.

Comment: how do I remove the point? If I delete this code `\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate[mark coordinate] (P);`, the code errors

Comment: @dustin replace `\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate[mark coordinate] (P);`
 with `\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate (P);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use package `tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere` at [here](https://github.com/matthias-wolff/tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere}
\begin{document}
 \def\r{3}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\path
 (0,0,0)  coordinate (O)
({\r*sin(80)}, {\r*cos(80)},\r) coordinate (A) ;
\fill[ball color=gray!10,tdplot_screen_coords] (O) circle (\r);
\foreach \a in {-75,-60,...,75}
 {\tdplotCsDrawLatCircle[]{\r}{\a}}
 \foreach \a in {0,15,...,165}
{\tdplotCsDrawLonCircle[]{\r}{\a}}
\draw[->,thick, blue] (O) -- (A);
\foreach \p in {A,O}
\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1.5pt);
\foreach \p/\g in {A/135,O/-90}
\path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]